# How do I prepend to a stream in Bash?

Tags: bash, stream, pipe, prepend

Suppose I have the following command in bash:

```
one | two
```

`one` runs for a long time producing a stream of output and `two` performs a quick operation on each line of that stream, but `two` doesn't work at all unless the first value it reads tells it how many values to read per line. `one` does not output that value, but I know what it is in advance (let's say it's `15`). I want to send a `15\n` through the pipe before the output of `one`. I do not want to modify `one` or `two`.

My first thought was to do:

```
echo "$(echo 15; one)" | two
```

That gives me the correct output, but it doesn't stream through the pipe at all until the command `one` finishes. I want the output to start streaming right away through the pipe, since it takes a long time to execute (months).

I also tried:

```
echo 15; one | two
```

Which, of course, outputs 15, but doesn't send it through the pipe to `two`.

Is there a way in bash to pass '15\n' through the pipe and then start streaming the output of `one` through the same pipe?

Comment: Have you tried grouping? `{ echo 15; one; } | two`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You just need the shell grouping construct:

```
{ echo 15; one; } | two
```

The spaces around the braces and the trailing semicolon are required.

To test:

```
one() { sleep 5; echo done; }
two() { while read line; do date "+%T - $line"; done; }
{ printf "%s\n" 1 2 3; one; } | two
```

```
16:29:53 - 1
16:29:53 - 2
16:29:53 - 3
16:29:58 - done
```

Comment: I `+1` you just because you mentioned _The spaces around the braces and the trailing semicolon are required_ (which would be the purpose of another question) and I didn't. `:)`

Answer (score 5):

Use [command grouping](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping):

```
{ echo 15; one; } | two
```

Done!

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with sed:

Example 'one' script, emits one line per second to show it's line buffered and running.

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ]; do
    echo "TICK $(date)"
    sleep 1
done
```

Then pipe that through this sed command, note that for your specific example 'ArbitraryText' will be the number of fields. I used ArbitraryText so that it's obvious that this is the inserted text. On OSX, **-l** is unbuffered with GNU Sed I believe it's **-u**

```
 $ ./one | sed -l '1i\
> ArbitraryText
> '
```

What this does is it instructs sed to insert one line before processing the rest of your file, everything else will pass through untouched.

The end result is processed line-by-line without chunk buffering (or, waiting for the input script to finish)

```
ArbitraryText
TICK Fri Jun 28 13:26:56 PDT 2013
...etc
```

You should be able to then pipe that into 'two' as you would normally.